# Using the same code twice in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, goto

I got a situation like below. 
somthing happens and the user needs to decide if he want's to proceed or not.
If he does not, the code stops executing.
If he does it will continue.

However rather than having the same code twice, I'd like that the part (a lot of code) is also executed when the if statment at the top returns a false.

In VB I would have used GOTO but there is no equivalent in Javascript.

```
if(true){
    var r = confirm("although this and that... do you still want to continue?");
    if (r == false) {
        break;
    } else { 
        a lot of code
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a `"` at the end of your `confirm`

Comment: what part of code you want to execute in else?JavaScript have return statement.

Comment: could you please elaborate..It is not very clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function

```
function confirmPop(){
   if(true){
    var r = confirm("although this and that... do you still want to continue?");
    if (r == false) {
        break;
    } else { 
        a lot of code
    }
  }
}
```

Then just call

```
confirmPop();
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems the most obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have something like this

```
if(booleanValue){
    var r = confirm("although this and that... do you still want to continue?");
    if (r == false) {
        break;
    } else { 
        a lot of code
    }
}else{
    a lot of code (the same as above)
}
```

in that case I would define a function with the contents of "a lot of code" and then call that function twice. Like this

```
function doALotOfWork(){
    a lot of code
}
if(booleanValue){
    var r = confirm("although this and that... do you still want to continue?");
    if (r == false) {
        break;
    } else { 
        doALotOfWork();
    }
}else{
    doALotOfWork();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = confirm("although this and that... do you still want to continue?");
// code to execute regardless of the option selected.
if (r) {
    // code to execute only if the user wants to continue.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the resuable logic into a function and inject a delegate (the method to call e.g. "a lot of other code") into the function...

```
var aLotOfCode = function () {
  // a lot of code here!
  console.log('a lot of code here!');
};


var confirmation = function (delegateIfRTrue)

  if(true){
    var r = confirm("although this and that... do you still want to continue?");
    if (r == false) {
        break;
    } else { 
        //a lot of code
        delegateIfRTrue();
    }
  }
```

And call it using...

```
confirmation(aLotOfCode);
```